# I'm getting 400 - bad request when i try to send date in JSON to backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i'm getting the 400 HTTP error every time I try to send some date object in JSON and i don't know why :(

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Scheduling implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", timezone = "Brazil/East")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 254)
    private Date initialDate;
    

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", timezone = "Brazil/East")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 254)
    private Date finalDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id")
    private Classroom classroom;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id")
    private Class group;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "equipments_schedulings",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "scheduling_id"), scheduling_id
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_id")) equipment_id
    private List<Equipment> equipments = new ArrayList<>();
```

and this is my JSON body:

```
{
    "initialDate": "22/11/2022 08:00",
    "finalDate": "22/11/2022 08:45",
    "teacher": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "group": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "classroom": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "equipment": [
        {
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

and I'm already have this on my application.properties file:

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=Brazil/East
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

It doesn't show any error on my console and I'm very confused.

If someone know what is happening I'll be very grateful ^^

Comment: (My java version is 17 and my springboot version is 2.7.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, we cannot assign `timezone` with a dynamic or a runtime value. It should be constant at compile time. Even enums are accepted.

So we should assign a constant to `timezone`.

```
private static final String TIME_ZONE="Brazil/East";
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", timezone = TIME_ZONE);
```

Comment: I put it, but was not :(

Comment: Could you please check the logs that are being generated by springboot. Maybe we can get more information related to this `Bad Request` from there. Based on that error, I can provide more comprehensive answer as to what might have gone wrong.

Comment: The logs from console? The console doesn't show any error.

Comment: With the tests I did, I noticed that the error only happens at finalDate